# VB script for Office: striping attachment from 1 SPECIFIC email address?

Tags: vba, email, outlook

I have the bare-bones of the script (see end of post) that I've modified from an existing (and working) copy we use here at my work. I need this script to look at a sender and if it's from "esupport@domainname.biz", THEN I want it to strip the attachment and dump it on a cloud drive we have here. But I only want the attachment if from that specific email address. We have other processes that use this same account and I don't want this code interfering with any of them. Any push in the right direction would be much appreciated, thank you so much.

My code:

```
Public Sub saveAttachtoDisk(itm As Outlook.MailItem)
Dim objAtt As Outlook.Attachment
Dim saveFolder As String

'Return sender's email

If Email.SenderEmailAddress = "esupport@domainname.biz" Then

    saveFolder = "v:\Anthony - Missing Invoices\Report"

     For Each objAtt In itm.Attachments

          objAtt.SaveAsFile saveFolder & "\" & objAtt.DisplayName

          Set objAtt = Nothing

     Next

End Sub
```

Comment: So... what's your question? What's not working exactly?

Comment: My apologies about the tags, they were suggested. I was under the impression though that vba and vb scripts were interchagnable, since visual basic is built into Office (vb script), but returns a vba error to me when my code fails. I fixed the tags.

Comment: As far as the what it does, ... it doesn't. It does nothing when I run it, nor does it return a message box.

Comment: it doesnt do anything because nothing is triggering it to run.  You need to call it from the Application.NewMail event if you want to check new emails.

Comment: So ...
`code
Private Sub Application_NewMail()
    Call 
`
 ...and here's where it loses me. I don't know what I'm calling.
Also, you're right, I had no trigger.. Can I still test the code by telling it to run manually? Is that possible?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot run this run code in this format directly. You have to pass itm.

Click in the code somewhere then F8 repeatedly to step through the code. You will not get a response.

A simple example, where there is an open mailitem.
You can pass itm to saveAttachtoDisk like this:

```
Sub run_saveAttachtoDisk
    dim currItem as mailitem
    set currItem = activeinspector.currentitem
    saveAttachtoDisk curritem
end sub
```

The usual method is to run the code on incoming mail in a rule. Choose saveAttachtoDisk in RunAScript.

The sender can be specified in the rule. If you do not want that then uncomment the if / end if statements.

You can do a "Run Rules Now" to process existing mail.

```
Public Sub saveAttachtoDisk(itm As Outlook.MailItem)

    Dim objAtt As Outlook.Attachment
    Dim saveFolder As String

    'If Email.SenderEmailAddress = "esupport@domainname.biz" Then

        saveFolder = "v:\Anthony - Missing Invoices\Report"

        For Each objAtt In itm.Attachments
            objAtt.SaveAsFile saveFolder & "\" & objAtt.DisplayName
        Next

    'end if

End Sub
```